# Camel FTP : how to log UnknowHostException or Connection failed

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have some camel config that is this...

```
  <from uri="ftp://user@testserverx?password=password&amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&amp;disconnect=true&amp;passiveMode=true&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotent=false" />
```

I would expect to see some error in the log about not being able to connect to **testserverx**
but I don't.

Anyone any idea why?

Notes:

camel-ftp : 2.13.2

Answer (score 0):

If I use your setup, the following expected error is logged:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: testserverx

Please make sure that the Camel context keeps alive before the first ftp poll. If using `org.apache.camel.spring.Main`, e.g. use the `run` method. This will run the process, and will wait until completed, or the JVM terminates:

```
final Main main = new Main();
main.setApplicationContextUri("path/to/spring/application/context.xml"); 
main.run();
```